# How to quickly return all artifacts and their properties in an Aritfactory repo?

Tags: python, rest, artifactory, artifactory-query-lang

We have an AQL that returns all folders that contain a specific file that contains various property keys and values, and then, for each artifact, we send GET request for `?properties` and `?general` as documented here: https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-ItemProperties so we can get the properties listed on the file and when the file was last modified. But with long list of files and to send two GET request for each file, the overall request slows down. Is there way to get all of the properties and all of the file in a single request, or is there a faster approach? The AQL itself runs fast, but having 2 subsequent requests slows down the overall process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [.include](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+Query+Language#ArtifactoryQueryLanguage-SpecifyingOutputFields) in your AQL, to get all results in one request.
In your case:
`.include("name","modified","property")`

I would recommend using the [Search Command](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory#CLIforJFrogArtifactory-SearchingFiles) of JFrog CLI. It also uses AQL internally, but you can your desired results in a more convenient manner.

Comment: Thank you! For `properties`, is there a way for the AQL to return a succinct mapping. With `?properties`, the return type is `{<key>: <value>, ...}`, but with the AQL, the return type is `[{key: <key>, value: <value>}, ...]`

Comment: @Flair With pleasure. Im unaware of a possible way to achieve this with the rest API. The CLI returns them as "props": {<key>: [<value>,<value>..],...} if that helps